# mono C# print persian text ubuntu

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, mono, bidi

I am using mono-develop under Ubuntu 14.04.
In my project I need to print Persian documents.
We are using native .net package system.drawing.
I ran the following code under Windows (mono which was installed on Windows) and
I had absolutely NO PROBLEM, but here under Ubuntu letters are not going to be joined together to create words. The output is something like this:

[image: rendered document by drawing]

I know somehow it is related to my OS. Please help me to solve this.

Here is my code:

```
namespace printPage{
    public class PrintClass
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog;
        PrintDocument printDocument;
        PageSetupDialog psd;

        public PrintClass()
        {
            printDialog = new PrintDialog ();
            printDocument = new PrintDocument();

            printDialog.Document = printDocument;

            printDocument.PrintPage += 
                new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(CreateReceipt);

            DialogResult result = printDialog.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                printDocument.Print();
        }

        public void CreateReceipt(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            //string to be printed out
            string txt = "با سلام و خسته نباشید";

            Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;
            Font font = new Font("Arial unicode MS", 20, FontStyle.Regular); //must use a mono spaced font as the spaces need to line up

            float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();
            int startX = 100;
            int startY = 100;

            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();  
            sf.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft;
            sf.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DisplayFormatControl;

            int faLCID = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa-IR").LCID;
            sf.SetDigitSubstitution(faLCID, StringDigitSubstitute.National);  

            graphic.DrawString( txt, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY, sf);
            e.HasMorePages = false;
        }
    }


    class MainClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            PrintClass p = new PrintClass ();
        }
    }
}
```